# Obtain marginal distribution from discrete joint pmf

Tags: probability, self-learning

I'm trying to learn how to obtain marginal distributions from a joint distribution and have been using the following exercise:

$P_{XY}(x,y)= \begin{cases}
\dfrac{e^{-60}60^x}{x!}\begin{pmatrix} x\\y \end{pmatrix}(0.3)^y(0.7)^{x-y},    &\text{if }x=0,1... &\text{and } y=0,...,x\\0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$

Here, I should find the marginal distributions of X and Y. The examples I've found for the discrete case are very simple, they are obtained using a table. Could you show me how should I proceed here in order to obtain the marginal distributions of X and Y?

Answer (score 0):

To get the marginal of X, for example, you need to "remove" the other variables. To do this, integrate the pmf over the range of Y.
$$\sum_{y=0}^{x}\dfrac{e^{-60}60^x}{x!} {x\choose y}(0.3)^y(0.7)^{x-y}$$
$$=\dfrac{e^{-60}60^x}{x!}\sum_{y=0}^{x} {x\choose y}(0.3)^y(1-0.3)^{x-y}$$

This is the pdf of the Binomial distribution, thus the above sum is equal to $1$. Thus:
$$\mathbb{P}[X=k]=\dfrac{e^{-60}60^x}{x!}$$
Thus X is poisson distributed with $\lambda=60$.

Comment: To get the marginal of Y, you need to sum the pdf from x=0 to infinity...however, this sum does not seem so straightforward to work out.

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I was thinking, I was trying this on paper.